# ESS R error: searching for program

Tags: ess, r

I have installed emacs on windows 10 working ok so far. Installed R and ESS.
Set system and user path to Rterm.exe as read in some forums.
Restarted and opened a R file in emacs. 
Syntax coloring is Ok, emacs entered ESS-R-mode but I cannot evaluate R code.

Using `C-c C-n` to evaluate the current line / selection, gives me a message:

```
"Searching for program: No such file or directory, R"
```

`M-x R` prompt for starting project directory, but same message is shown.

Double checked system PATH and everything seems ok. 
Checked emacs variable "getenv" and path is properly set to Rterm.exe folder.

I can open a shell inside emacs and run R prompt with no issue.

any hint?

UPDATE:
tried setting (inferior-R-program-name "C:/Users/joe/R/bin/x64/Rterm") and (inferior-ess-r-program "C:/Users/joe/R/bin/x64/Rterm.exe") to .emacs file and now emacs is stuck on blank screen after asking for R starting project directory. The only way to close it is Task Manager - kill process

Comment: what does `(executable-find "R")` return?

Comment: How to execute such command? I've tried M-x but helm did not find such

Comment: open the scratch buffer using `C-x b`, write down `(executable-find "R")`, go to end of line and type `C-x C-e`

Comment: answer is nil. Seems that some other variable needs to be set

Comment: tried setting (inferior-R-program-name "C:/Users/joe/R/bin/x64/Rterm") and (inferior-ess-r-program "C:/Users/joe/R/bin/x64/Rterm.exe") to .emacs file and now emacs is stuck on blank screen after asking for R starting project directory. The only way to close it is Task Manager - kill process

Comment: It seems that asking for R starting project directory is expected behaviour: http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Starting-up ... Here's a sample file, but it doesn't look like anything different http://members.cbio.mines-paristech.fr/~thocking/primer.html#sec-2.2 ... you might need to take it up to the developers here: https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues

Comment: Have the same problem - there has been a "init.el" file to say Emacs where the Rterm.exe is. However cannot find it in the recent ESS Emacs distribution (Windows). Can anybody advise where to put the pat to Rterm.exe?
Many thanks!
Zdenek

Comment: Can you run R outside of Emacs? Can you show us your .emacs?

Answer (score 3):

It's no longer required to use Rterm.exe; you can just use R.exe directly. To configure the program name that emacs/ESS uses, set the variable in your .emacs like this:

```
(setq inferior-ess-r-program "R")
```

Alternatively, press `C-h v`, select the `inferior-ess-r-program` variable, and use the Customize interface to set and save the setting.

If you don't have the Windows Path set correctly to include the R/bin folder, you can specify the full path in the setting.

```
(setq inferior-ess-r-program "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/bin/R.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `(executable-find "R")` returns `nil`, you can add the R location to `exec-path` through Customize. On my system, `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.1\bin\x64`. This will resolve the issue.

The easiest way to do this is to `C-h v exec-path` and then click through the "customize" option link. (Note that `exec-path` is both a variable and a function, and you want the variable.)