# ESS installation does not initialize flymake

Tags: ess, flymake

I install ESS following [these directions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48341/unable-to-install-ess-package), adding these to `~/.emacs`:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

then typing `M-x package-install RET ess RET`, and adding this to `~/.emacs` as well:

```
(require 'ess-site)
```

Now when I open an R file in Emacs, I get this message in a buffer:

```
Warning (flymake): Disabling backend ess-r-flymake because (error Cannot find program ’R’)
Warning (flymake): Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)
Warning (flymake): Disabling backend ess-r-flymake because (error Cannot find program ’R’)
Warning (flymake): Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)
```

and typing in the buffer with the R file is slower because of warnings from `Flymake`.

I have also set the inferior R program as in [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42537/ess-r-error-searching-for-program):

```
(setq inferior-ess-r-program "R")
```

But the result is the same.

How can I fix this?

Comment: ESS seems not to find R. Have you read an tried the comments ftom the second thread that you link to? Is R working okay from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I read and tried those comments, which is why I added the `inferior-ess-r-program` command. R works OK from the command line and is at `/usr/local/bin/R
`.

Comment: what does (executable-find "R") return? In your case it should be /usr/local/bin/R

Comment: @andrej Yes, running `M-:` `(executable-find "R")` displays `"/usr/local/bin/R"` in the mini-buffer.

Comment: Sorry! Then I don't know what to do. On my system ess-r-flymake isn't called when I open an R file. Would suggest asking on the ESS github page.

Comment: @andrej I'm at a loss as well, especially because the setup worked fine with ESS installed from source and appeared when I switched to ESS from MELPA.

Comment: @andrej The problem has now disappeared and setting the inferior process was the answer, along with disabling legacy stuff from flymake, as I wrote [here](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/883). I don't know why Emacs behaved differently then compared to now. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: Noce! It's perfectly fine to answer your question yourself. I do think that you have a better answer that closes this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### R executable

I confirm that `flymake` can now find the `R` executable. The line `(setq inferior-ess-r-program "/usr/local/bin/R")` was the problem: without the line, I `(executable-find "R")` returns `nil` and I get this warning twice:

```
Warning (flymake): Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)
```

I added that line to my `~/.emacs` on March 26, so I don't understand why the changes did not take effect 4 days after, even though I turn off the computer every day.

### `Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake`

Now I get only this message:

```
Warning (flymake): Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)
Warning (flymake): Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)
```

I found that [I could disable the legacy stuff](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/Disable-flymake-log-about-proc-legacy-flymake-td454765.html) with

```
(remove-hook 'flymake-diagnostic-functions 'flymake-proc-legacy-flymake)
```

So, although the last one is quick-and-dirty, it works for me.

Cross-posted from [Github issue](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/883).

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.