# Problem with Flycheck and Python

Tags: python, flycheck

I think that this is a newbie question, but here it goes:

I have installed Flycheck just as in the [official page](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/). Therefore, in my `.emacs` file I added the following lines (after installing):

```
(package-install 'flycheck)
(global-flycheck-mode)
(package-install 'exec-path-from-shell)
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

However, when I open a `.py` file, I get this error message:

> Warning [flymake seila.py]: Disabling backend python-flymake because (error Cannot find a suitable checker)
>
> Warning [flymake seila.py]: Disabling backend flymake-proc-legacy-flymake because (error Can’t find a suitable init function)

How would I fix these errors? Seems to me that some file/configuration is missing. I've found [this (partial) solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50505/29251) that makes the second error disappear, but It does not seem to be an effective solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your warning messages (notice that they say "warning" rather than "error") come from `flymake` which is a package similar to `flycheck` except it comes bundled with Emacs.  So those messages are not directly related to your `flycheck` config.

Comment: Thanks for noticing my typos! I don't even know `flymake`. Do you think is it safe to disable it?

Comment: @JoséJoaquim: It's not enabled by default, so it must be enabled by something in your config.  Rather than disable it, you can probably make it work by installing  `pyflakes` (and use it instead of `flycheck`).